# Sorting a list of servers located in same location by distance then load

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of Servers (title,load,distance)
 The initial list has been grouped by distance.

- LOC1 S1 : Load NULL - 3km
- LOC1 S2 : Load 0.1  - 3km
- LOC1 S3 : Load 0.6  - 3km
- LOC1 S4 : Load 0.2  - 3km
- LOC2 S1 : Load 0.7  - 1km
- LOC2 S2 : Load 0.1  - 1km
- LOC2 S3 : Load 0.2  - 1km
- LOC3 S1 : Load 0.1  - 2km

I am trying to write a Linq query that does the follows:
For each grouped list of server by location take the least loaded item (Load item with null should be ignored and pushed to the back of the output list).Then repeat the same for the second least loaded item from each group. IF we apply that logic then we should get:

First least loaded item of each group ordered by distance:

First step is to have an ordered list of items grouped by distance.
As distance is the key for each group.

From first group 1st least

- Loc 2 S2: Load 0.1 - 1km

Next group is Loc 3

- Loc 3 S1: Load 0.1 - 2km

Next group is Loc 1

- Loc 1 S2: Load 0.1 - 3km

From first group 2nd least loaded

- LOC2 S3: Load 0.2 - 2km

Next group

- LOC1 S4: Load 0.2  -3km

Note there was no location 3 as it does not have a second load of 0.2

Finally third least loaded item is...

- LOC2 S1: Load 0.7 - 1km

Next Group

- LOC 1 S3: Load 0.6 3km

If we group each of these up we have:

1st group:

- Loc 2 S2: Load 0.1 - 1km
- Loc 3 S1: Load 0.1 - 2km
- Loc 1 S2: Load 0.1 - 3km

2nd group

- LOC2 S3: Load 0.2 - 2km
- LOC1 S4: Load 0.2  -3km

3rd group

- LOC2 S1: Load 0.7 - 1km

Next Group

- LOC 1 S3: Load 0.6 3km

Finally summing these up to be sorted by distance then load for each group:

- LOC 2 S2: Load 0.1 - 1km
- LOC 3 S1: Load 0.1 - 2km
- LOC 1 S2: Load 0.1 - 3km
- LOC 2 S3: Load 0.2 - 2km
- LOC 1 S4: Load 0.2 - 3km
- LOC 2 S1: Load 0.7 - 1km
- LOC 1 S3: Load 0.6 - 3km

I have tried the following sync:

```
var orderedbyLoad = servers.OrderBy(t=>t.Load);
var groupByDistance = orderedbyLoad.GroupBy(a=>a.Distance,s=>s);
```

This should give an ordered groups by distance with list of servers ordered by load in each group.

The next step is where i am having issues. I want to use some sort of take logic for each group and then cycle through the next loaded item in each group. These takes should all project to a flat list as shown above respecting the distance then load order But i am not sure how to do this with linq???

The problem is with the last two items. If I run your query I get
var groupedByDistance = servers.Where(x => x.Load != null).OrderBy(x => x.Load).ThenBy(x => x.Distance);

see:

- LOC 2 S2 Load 0.1 Dist 1
- LOC 3 S1 Load 0.1 Dist 2
- LOC 1 S2 Load 0.1 Dist 3
- LOC 2 S3 Load 0.2 Dist 1
- LOC 1 S4 Load 0.2 Dist 3
- LOC 1 S3 Load 0.6 Dist 3
- LOC 2 S1 Load 0.7 Dist 1

As distance should come first then load Loc2 S1 Load 0.7 should be before Loc1 S3 Load 0.6 @shameel

I was reviewing my pseudo and therefore i came up with my implementation:

```
   static IEnumerable<Server> Zip(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Server>> groups)
    {
       bool repeat = true;
       int i=0;
       while(repeat)
       {
            repeat = false;

            foreach (var grp in groups)
            {
                var element = grp.Skip(i).ElementAtOrDefault(0);
                if (element != null)
                {
                    repeat = true;
                    yield return element;
                }
            }

            i++;
        } 
    }
```

The only difference from yours is while plus i think it ElementAtDefault(0)
should work the same.
Regards

Shameel

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

Being `servers` a raw (non grouped) list of servers:

```
servers.Where(x => x.Load != null).OrderBy(x => x.Load).ThenBy(x => x.Distance)
```

If I understood well, that should give you a list ordered by the closest distance and then by the smallest load.

If you want to add the "null loads" to the end of the list:

```
servers.Where(x => x.Load != null).OrderBy(x => x.Load).ThenBy(x => x.Distance).Concat(servers.Where(x => x.Load == null))
```

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

EDIT: That one didn't respect the exact order between groups. In order to achieve that you should iterate "manually" through each group, with this code and your test case, I got the expected results:

```
        List<Server> serversList = new List<Server>();
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S1", Location = "LOC1", Distance = 3, Load = null });
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S2", Location = "LOC1", Distance = 3, Load = 1 });
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S3", Location = "LOC1", Distance = 3, Load = 6 });
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S4", Location = "LOC1", Distance = 3, Load = 2 });
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S1", Location = "LOC2", Distance = 1, Load = 7 });
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S2", Location = "LOC2", Distance = 1, Load = 1 });
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S3", Location = "LOC2", Distance = 1, Load = 2 });
        serversList.Add(new Server { Name = "S1", Location = "LOC3", Distance = 2, Load = 1 });

        List<Server> orderedList = new List<Server>();

        var serversByDistance = serversList.Where(x => x.Load != null)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Distance)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Distance)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.OrderBy(s => s.Load).ToList());

        for (int i = 0; i < serversByDistance.Values.Max(x => x.Count); i++)
        {
            foreach (var key in serversByDistance.Keys)
            {
                var element = serversByDistance[key].ElementAtOrDefault(i);

                if (element != null)
                    orderedList.Add(element);
            }
        }
```

You can then add the null results to `orderedList` if you want.

(NOTE: I did the test with int types for simplicity...just for saving some characters when typing :P )

Comment: I ran your query see my amended comment. It does not give the correct order for the last two items

Comment: The result list should respect distance then load order from each group. Where items in a group are less in load but higher in distance then they should be reorderd.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I do not know whether this can be done in an elegant way, but you can pass your `groupByDistance` to a method like this:

```
IEnumerable<Server> Zip(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Server>> groups)
{
    bool cont;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        cont = false;
        foreach (var grp in groups)
        {
            var element = grp.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();
            if (element != null)
            {
                cont = true;
                yield return element;
            }
        }
        ++i;
    } while (cont);
}
```

which will return an `IEnumerable` so it can be used in further LINQ queries if needed. It also features delayed enumeration. But - it is definitely not elegant.

My complete sandbox for trying this out, //option2 is your alternative:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqTest01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Server> servers = new List<Server>{
                new Server(){ load = null, distance = 3 },
                new Server(){ load = 0.1, distance = 3 },
                new Server(){ load = 0.6, distance = 3 },
                new Server(){ load = 0.2, distance = 3 },
                new Server(){ load = 0.7, distance = 1 },
                new Server(){ load = 0.1, distance = 1 },
                new Server(){ load = 0.2, distance = 1 },
                new Server(){ load = 0.1, distance = 2 },
                };

            // option 1
            var sorted = from server in servers orderby server.load where server.load != null select server;
            var groups = from server in sorted
                       group server by server.distance into bydistance
                       orderby bydistance.Key
                       select bydistance
                       ;

            var final1 = Zip(groups);

            // option 2
            var orderedbyLoad = servers.OrderBy(t => t.load);
            var groupByDistance = orderedbyLoad.GroupBy(a => a.distance, s => s);
            var final2 = Zip(groups);
        }

        static IEnumerable<Server> Zip(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Server>> groups)
        {
            bool cont;
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                cont = false;
                foreach (var grp in groups)
                {
                    var element = grp.Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (element != null)
                    {
                        cont = true;
                        yield return element;
                    }
                }
                ++i;
            } while (cont);
        }
    }

    class Server
    {
        public double? load;
        public int distance;
    }

}
```

Comment: is this method to take from each group using a yield to remember the position so the next iteration will start from the next item   in the group. Just trying to understand  this method.

Comment: i think the parameter should be IGrouping<Key,Element>

Comment: @shameel Yes, exactly. Takes i-th element from each group (inside `foreach`) and goes incrementing `i` until at least one group happened to have an element at that position.

Comment: @shmeel Parameter: perhaps so, `IGrouping<int, IEnumerable<Server>>`? I'm not sure. But `IEnumerable` is ok, as `IGrouping` derives from it.

Comment: thanks that was helpful. I still get the last two results in the wrong order. I was thinking if IComparable will help. However, comparing two server objects with different loads and distance is problematic i think... it would only work with two server objects with same load and different distance in that case return compare to on the distance would order by least distance first

Comment: everything is working in terms of sorting but this scenarios with the last two items is really tricky

Comment: What should the last two be like? I guess I'm missing something from the original question then.

Comment: it should be 
LOC 2 S1 Load 0.7 Dist 1 then LOC 1 S3 Load 0.6 Dist 3. The requirement is to take(6) from the output list so this means if LOC 2 S1 Load 0.7 Dist 1 should be the 6th element. However with the current code I am getting LOC 1 S3 Load 0.6 Dist 3

Comment: 0.7/1 and 0.6/3 is exactly what I'm getting. It should never come to take(6), maximum in a group should be 4 for the group of distance 3.

Comment: your code orders correctly by load by distance however in the case of 0.6 and 0.7 load we want distance to take precedence. That is the stupid requirement i have.

Comment: But it does, that's what I'm saying. The resulting order of my code is:
`distance 1/load 0.1

distance 2/load 0.1

distance 3/load 0.1

distance 1/load 0.2

distance 3/load 0.2

distance 1/load 0.7

distance 3/load 0.6`

Comment: @shameel Cool :) What was the problem?

Comment: i am just intrigued how you got to the solution of the zip. I was trying to think  of a solution like that. So from your code you first order by load then group by distance. You then pass it to your zip which then does the ordering for each item in each group

Comment: Well, it's not that nice a code. The first ordering and grouping is LINQuish, same as yours. Then it's 'classical' procedural approach, only with the advantage of `yield return`, so the actual resulting list does not have to be enumerated until you actually iterate through it (@rualmar has an answer that enumerates twice, though I'd say the code is more readable.) Please mark one of the answers as accepted if you think this is what you were looking for.